Are the $\Pi_1$ functions a strict intermediary between $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$?
This question has to do with categorizing arithmetically definable functions. A total function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is said to be $\Pi_1$ precisely when there exists a $\Pi_1$ formula $\phi(x,y)$ such that $f(x)=y \iff \phi(x,y)$, with similar definitions for $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$ functions. Due to Post's theorem, a total function is $\Sigma_n$ if and only if it's $\Delta_n$, and these are exactly the functions which are computable from the $n$'th Turing jump. In particular, the $\Delta_1$ functions are exactly the computable functions, and the $\Delta_2$ functions are exactly those which are computable given an oracle to the halting problem. Naturally, every $\Delta_1$ function is also $\Pi_1$, and every $\Pi_1$ function is also $\Delta_2$. My question is twofold, regarding the converse of those last two assertions.


Does there exist a $\Pi_1$ function which is not $\Delta_1$, i.e. it's uncomputable?




Does there exist a $\Delta_2$ function which is not $\Pi_1$?


I thought of this question when I realized that I had been naively thinking that $\Pi_1$ functions would collapse to $\Delta_1$, similar to how all $\Sigma_1$ total functions are $\Delta_1$. Once I realized my carelessness, I suspected my first question above question would be true. However, I had a lot of trouble producing an explicit example, and I even got a partial result to the contrary (theorem below). Assuming it's proved true however, it would indicate that the $\Pi_1$ functions are a distinct class from $\Delta_1$ functions. That raised the further question of whether $\Pi_1$ is instead identical to $\Delta_2$, hence the second question.

Theorem: If $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ is $\Pi_1$, and $f$ is bounded by a computable function, then $f$ is computable. 
proof: Let $g:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ be a computable function which bounds $f(n)\leq g(n)$ for all $n$. Since $f$ is $\Pi_1$, then its graph is co-enumerable, so we have a computable function which enumerates all and only the ordered pairs which are not in the graph of $f$. To compute $f(n)$, first compute $g(n)$ and prepare an empty list, and then start enumerating all pairs not in the graph of $f$. Each time we encounter a pair of the form $(n,y)$, include the value $y$ to our list. Finally, each time our list is updated, check to see how many elements our list has. If our list contains all but one value $y\leq g(n)$, then halt and return that unique missing value. This algorithm is guaranteed to halt, and the unique missing value is necessarily $f(n)$ exactly, hence $f$ is computed by this algorithm. $\square$

The answer to both questions is yes, the set of $\Pi_1$ functions is a strict intermediary between $\Delta_1$ and $\Delta_2$. Your theorem strongly hints at how to answer both questions. Consider the following paraphrase of your theorem: it's impossible for a function to simultaneously be uncomputable, and $\Pi_1$, and computably bounded.
To produce a function which is $\Delta_2$ but not $\Pi_1$, per your theorem, it suffices to find a bounded uncomputable function. A simple example is the halting problem oracle, which is obviously uncomputable and trivially bounded by the constant $2$.

The halting oracle, which returns $1$ whenever its input is (a numeric code for) a halting Turing machine and returns $0$ otherwise, is $\Delta_2$ but not $\Pi_1$.

Similarly, to produce a function which is uncomputable and $\Pi_1$, your theorem necessitates that it grow extremely quickly. Hence, we're inclined to search for fast-growing functions which are nearly computable. The most famous example, the Busy Beaver function, is indeed an uncomputable $\Pi_1$ function. Originally I considered the definition of $BB$ which scores machines based on how many $1$'s they write, and although that function is $\Pi_1$ too, the proof was really complicated and didn't generalize. Instead, I consider the definition of Busy Beaver to be the maximum halting time. The nontrivial portion of the following claim is proven at the end of my answer.

The Busy Beaver function $BB(n)$, defined as the largest halting time of any $n$-state Turing machine, is an uncomputable $\Pi_1$ function.

Both of these observations generalize up the arithmetical hierarchy. For any $n$, there will exist some $\Delta_{n+1}$ function which is not $\Pi_n$, in particular the halting oracle corresponding to the $n$'th Turing jump. Similarly, there will exist some $\Pi_n$ function which is not $\Delta_n$, in particular the Busy Beaver defined relative to the $n$'th Turing Jump.

Theorem: The busy beaver function $BB(n)$ has a $\Pi_1$ graph. 
proof: Consider the computable predicate $P(n,y)$ which simulates, in parallel, every $n$-state Turing machine until at least time $y$. If there doesn't exist a machine which halted at exactly the $y$'th step, then $P(n,y)$ should halt. Otherwise, continue simulating all those machines until some new machine halts after time $y$, and if that occurs, then $P(n,y)$ should halt.
Notice that if $BB(n)<y$, then necessarily our machine will halt in the first case. If instead $BB(n)>y$, then our machine will halt in the second case if $y$ happens to be the halting time of some non-champion Turing machine, and otherwise we'd halt in the first case again. In the final case that $BB(n)=y$, our algorithm will fail to halt in the first case since there is a machine which halts exactly at time $y$, but it also fails to halt in the second case since there's no machine with a halting time larger than $y$. Therefore, $P(n,y)$ halts if and only if $BB(n)\neq y$. This proves that the complement of the graph of $BB$ is semidecidable, i.e. $\Sigma_1$, and therefore $BB$ is a $\Pi_1$ function. $\square$
